# parsley js remote returning xml rather than json in ajax

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I am making an ajax request using the following code:

```
 $('#useremail').parsley().addAsyncValidator(
    'validateUsername', function (xhr) {
     return 200 === xhr.status;
     return 404 === xhr.status; 
   }, '/CheckEmailAvailability',
      { "type": "POST", "dataType": "json", "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8" } 
);

 <input id="useremail" type="text" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" data-parsley-required-message="Vänligen ange en giltig e-postadress" data-parsley-remote-validator="validateUsername" name="Email" required />
```

Seems all i am sending is a string as per the console:

And i get the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.domain/Central/Login/">{"availaibility":"EMAIL_ALREADY_EXIST"}</string>
```

How to i send the proper Json and get a response in JSON format?

ANy help will much be appreciated.

FYI i am using parsley v 2.02

Comment: revised the js, now i have:    { "type": "POST", "dataType": "json", "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "data": '{"email": "' + field + '" }' }

Comment: response is ok. But my field remains empty "". var field = $("#useremail").val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send some data to the the server:

```
data: JSON.stringify({key:value, key2:value2}),
```

and add the correct content type:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

Comment: is the JSON stringify not already handled by Parsley behind the scene?

Comment: RIght. Just send the data without stringifing it.

Comment: I now get this response: "Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: email.","StackTrace":"...etc

Comment: i don't think i am far.. as now i get the tab JSON.. its just i am still sending a string :(